# Jump to Item which isn't fetched yet (GraphQL / Apollo Frontend)

Tags: javascript, pagination, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I display tons of components on my page. I have a feature that allows the user to type in the *name* of a component and then **jump to that component** via `scrollIntoView`, using the `id`. This currently works because I do have all my components rendered on the page (thus in the DOM).

**Problem:**

I'd like to use Apollos `fetchMore` helper, and only show 50 components at a time. But this will remove the other components from the DOM, so it seems my `jumpToComponent()` function will break: Say a user is on page 1 (components 1-50) and wants to jump to component no. 80.